# C# multi-dimensional array, ArrayList, or hash table?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, hashtable

I'm trying to figure out how to build a multi-dimensional "array" that is:

- flexible size
- use 2 keys
- 1st key is int (flexible)
- 2nd key is string (kind of limited)

The use will be like:

```
console.writelen(array[0]["firstname"]);
console.writelen(array[0]["lastname"]);
console.writelen(array[0]["phone"]);

console.writelen(array[1]["firstname"]);
console.writelen(array[1]["lastname"]);
console.writelen(array[1]["phone"]);

.....
.....

console.writelen(array[x]["firstname"]);
console.writelen(array[x]["lastname"]);
console.writelen(array[x]["phone"]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure it wouldn't be more appropriate to create a class/struct to contain the data? For example:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then you'd just create an array of `Person`:

```
var array = new Person[1];
array[0] = new Person() { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Smith", Phone = "foo" };
```

Or, since you say "flexible size", maybe you'd want a list instead:

```
var list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person());
```

**Update**: The syntax used to set `array[0]` in the first example is an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx); the following two snippets are roughly equivalent:

```
var foo = new Person();
foo.FirstName = "John";

var bar = new Person() { FirstName = "John" };
```

So yes, you could just call `list.Add(new Person() { ... })` if you wanted to. You could also make use of collection initializers in this case:

```
var john = new Person() { FirstName = "John" };
var joe = new Person() { FirstName = "Joe" };
var list = new List<Person>() { john, joe };
```

Comment: var list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person());

very interesting

how to add the values?

list.Add(new Person(){ FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Smith", Phone = "foo" });

like this?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use this:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Use it like this:

```
var dd = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
dd[5] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dd[5]["a"] = "foo";
```

You can also create a new class to simplify the creation of the inner dictionary:

```
class DDict { // optional: generic
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> _Inner = new ...;

    public Dictionary<string, string> this (int index) {
        Dictionary<string, string> d;
        if (!_Inner.TryGetValue(index, out d)) {
             d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
             _Inner.Add(index, d);
        }
        return d;
    }
}

var dd = new DDict();
dd[5]["a"] = "hi";
```

If the first index is sequential, you can of course also just use an array of dictionaries:

```
var dd = new Dictionary<string, string>[128];
```

Also, if the inner members are always the same, I suggest to create a new class and access it in an array:

```
class Dat {
    string name;
    string phone;
}
var list = new Dat[128]

// access:
list[5].name = "matt";
```

Instead of an array, you could also use a `List` or a `Dictionary<int, Dat>` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with an Array unless you have a single Array of KeyValuePair<int,string>, but I think you really want a Dictionary<int,string>.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dic[0] = "zero";
dic[1] = "one";
dic[2] = "two";

foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in dic)
{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Key: {0}, Value: {1}",kvp.Key,kvp.Value);

}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't pick up on the 2 keys part.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just see two dimensions. The first one is a row index, the second is a column index. And this sounds like a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to me.

Comment: in that case in this example http://dotnetperls.com/datatable-foreach
how to show the item label{name,phone} instead of "item:"

cheers